# Need help getting a while loop to work with a list in python

Tags: python, function, while-loop, temperature

I am making a small program using a while loop to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius by taking the temps from a list and sending it to a function for calculation.  Once it converts the temp from F to C it will print the result for each temp.  I am not looking to have the code written for me, I am just looking for some information to get me in the right direction.  This is what I have so far, but I don't think that I need the for loop in it. temp is supposed to be each temperature in Fahrenheit and the add function is supposed to convert it to Celsius.

```
def add(x):
    return float(x - 32) * 5.0/9.0


temp = [-10, -2, 7, 16, 24, 32, 41, 50, 58, 67, 75]
while True:
    for x in temp:

        print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `while True` loop.  And you don't want to print the items in `temp`; you want to print the *result* of calling `add()` on each item in `temp`.

```
for x in temp:
    print(add(x))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I see where I made the mistakes.  I ended up just removing the while loop and changing the print statement and it works properly now.